# Javascript assign value of variable inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to create several layers for OpenLayers. I loop through the array and assign values for each values in using `typename: 'Test:' + item.ServiceName`. The problem is when the OpenLayer calls the function it grabs the last assigned value of item.ServiceName which is always "Test_Layer_3" so Test_Layer_1 and Test_Layer_2 are not used.

How can I change it so that Test_Layer_1, Test_Layer_2, Test_Layer_3 are assigned to typename?

```
    var _MyLayers = [];
    _MyLayers.push({ "Id": 0, "ServiceName": "Test_Layer_1" });
    _MyLayers.push({ "Id": 1, "ServiceName": "Test_Layer_2" });
    _MyLayers.push({ "Id": 2, "ServiceName": "Test_Layer_3" });

    for (var i = 0; i < _MyLayers.length; i++)
    {
        var item = _MyLayers[i];

        var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
            loader: function (extent)
            {
                $.ajax('http://localhost/geoserver/wfs', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        service: 'WFS',
                        version: '1.1.0',
                        request: 'GetFeature',
                        typename: 'Test:' + item.ServiceName,
                        srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                        outputFormat: 'application/json',
                        bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                    }
                });
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({})),
        });
        var layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: sourceVector,
            minResolution: 0,
            maxResolution: 2,
            style: new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "rgba(25, 163, 255, 1.5)", width: 1 }) })
        });

        _MapLayers.push(layerVector);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up assigning the value of `item.ServiceName` to sourceVector. Then reading the value of sourceVector inside the loader function.

Answer (score 1):

**It should work by replacing `item.ServiceName` with `_MyLayers[i].ServiceName`.**

### Explanation

When you define the `loader` functions it does not mean `item.ServiceName` is assigned to `typename` at that moment. Instead the function maintains a link to your `item` variable (sort of), which then links back to the value of `_MyLayers[i]` — a global.

When the `loader` function is called for each object by OpenLayers, `'Test:' + item.ServiceName,` is evaluated and assigned to `typename` where the value represented by `item` has since changed. It will now point to the last item (e.g. `_MyLayers[3]`) since it was the last value `item` was assigned.

By replacing the line above, the `loader` functions now each maintain a unique link directly to the global `_MyLayers`. As `i` is a number, each loader function implements a statement based on the value of `i` at the time the function was defined in your `for` loop (e.g. `_MyLayers[1]`, `_MyLayers[2]`, ... and so on).

Comment: I like your idea. I tried using your code and it maintains the last value of `i`.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I'm curious as to why `i` keeps the last value. I'll leave the following code for anyone else who stumbles here:
`var items = [{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}], i, result = [];

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 
 /* add function definition */
 result.push(function () {
  return "val: " + items[i].name;
 });
}

/* log to console */
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 console.log(result[i]());
}`
It's output:
`val: 1
val:2`. It worked in this case, maybe not correctly approximate your situation, but i